# AngularJS selector like jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, jquery-selectors

I have 3 div element with same class in a HTML code as:

```
<div class="hide">
</div>

<div class="hide">
</div>

<div class="hide">
</div>
```

In jQuery I can hide all the div in only one code statement: `$(".hide").hide();`. How we can hide all the div in single code statement in angular js?

Comment: I have tried it with ng-show/ ng-hide, but is there any alternate way, where i can take only selector and hide all the elements from DOM in angular JS?

Comment: What about `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity = '0'`; ?

Comment: The proper way to do this in Angular is ng-show/ng-hide.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* so something like this (mixing AngularJS/jQuery):

```
var results = $document[0].getElementsByClassName("hide");
angular.forEach(results, function(result) {
    var wrappedResult = angular.element(result);
    wrappedResult.hide();
});
```

However, mixing jQuery into AngularJS application is typically frowned upon, and this just looks like really dirty code that I wouldn't want in a production app.

The **best approach** and the **"Angular" way** to do it would be to just wrap your multiple `<div>`s with an outer `<div>` and use `ng-show`/`ng-hide`.

```
<div ng-hide="someTrueVariable">
    <div class="hide"></div>

    <div class="hide"></div>

    <div class="hide"></div>
</div>
```

If you are coming from a jQuery background and are moving into AngularJS, I would *highly* suggest you take a look at the following Stack Overflow thread. I really think this will help put you into an AngularJS development mindset:
    ["Thinking in AngularJS" if I have a jQuery background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: Hence the "_could_" followed by the "Angular" way to do it to demonstrate why you don't want to think like a jQuery developer when working within AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

Put class of element in the attribute `hide-element`;

HTML :

```
<div hide-element="hide" class="hide">
    hide1
  </div>  
  <div hide-element="hide">
    hide2
  </div>
  <div hide-element="hide" class="hide">
    hide3
  </div>
```

JS :

Use `hideElement` attribute to get class name and hide those element having this class

```
.directive('hideElement', function() {

    return {  
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        hideElement: '@'
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attr) {

        var className = scope.hideElement;
        ele.bind('click', function($event) {

          angular.element(document.querySelectorAll("." + className))
            .css('display', 'none');
        })
      }
    }
  })
```

Working [demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/o6QHXQb94DzM4r6pinlD?p=preview)